# How To Call A JavaScript Function Returned From NodeJS in ReactJS JSX

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I want to make a function that creates a button in the React DOM.
That function should be returned from NodeJS.

NodeJS - localhost:8000/stripe-form returns:

```
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

In ReactJS:

```
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/stripe-form"></script>
        </div>
      );
}
```

How can I do something similar to this in JSX:

```
<button onClick={myFunction} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Something like this may do the trick (using https://github.com/axios/axios for data loading).

```
async function createMarkup() {
  const htmlData = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/stripe-form")
  return {__html: htmlData};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```